# Odoo using all of an item in a automatic manufacturing order

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

As I am attempting to set up a new installation of Odoo I am trying to figure out how to use the manufacturing tool correctly.

What I am trying to do is take a roll of material and cut it down to sheets. In this case one roll equals 30 sheets.

Is there a way to tell Odoo that when I request 10 sheets that it should use the entire roll and create 30 sheets so that I'm not left with a fraction of a roll?

EDIT: I figured out that i can set the product rounding of the consumed item to be set to one full item. But now i have a different problem. If I ask Odoo to produce say 40 items it will produce exactly 40 and use 2 rolls, which means im missing 20 items. Is there a way to set the produced quantity to a factor of the amount of items i can get out of the roll?

Answer (score 0):

You could create:

1. A product called sheet-Unit
2. Then in the BOM page of the sheet-unit you write 40 units under quantity and you put your roll as BOM. Basically you're saying that 40 unit of sheet-unit = BOM
3. Sheet for sales (your sales product) BOM = 1 sheet-unit

Then test it.

When you sell a sheet-sales-product and a sheet-unit is needed according with your settings (make to order - manufacturing - minimum qantity in stock-etc) a MO for 40 sheet should start.